# How to get a part of a current content in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

My question is: How can I get a part of a current content in Umbraco CMS in backend file (*.master.cs)? About 350 characters, but i'm sure, that a large does not matter. Is there any useful method to do it?
Umbraco version: 4.6.2.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself:

```
   string part = currentNode.GetProperty("bodyText").Value.Substring(0, 450) + "...";
```